# Passing dictionary value into pandas.dataframe.query reutrns UndefinedVariableError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary like such:

```
dict = {'x':[2,6,4],'y':[56,5,1]}
```

I would like to pass one of these lists into the query method:

```
new_df = df.query('col3 == @dict["x"]')
```

But I get a UndefinedVariableError. Is there any way to do what I want without the roundabout step of setting a new variable and then using "@" with that one

```
new_v = dict['x']
new_df = df.query('col3 == @new_v')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you definetly need the query function?
Otherwise following the [example in the query docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) you could try something like:

```
df.loc[df['col3'].isin(dict['x'])]
```

Note that the [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), might be required since your dictionary returns a list

Answer (score 1):

So you want something like ?

```
df.query('col3=={}'.format(dict['x']))
```